# django-haystack order_by not working

Tags: django, search, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I have a query like

```
SearchQueryset().all().models(Show).order_by('title')
```

This will return list of objects. But in the title names there might be the special characters like `./hack:twilight` and also numbers like `009:absolute`.

According to `order_by` documentation, the priority goes to special characters. But when I see the output, it starts from the numbers.

Basically I need this output using that query

```
>> list = ['apple', 'zebra', '.hack', 'orange', 'car', 'funk', 'python']
>>> list.sort()
>>> list
['.hack', 'apple', 'car', 'funk', 'orange', 'python', 'zebra']
```

Any idea?

Comment: I think this will differ depending on which database you are using.

Comment: @elethan I am using PostgreSQL database.